# How do I read the html from an HttpResponse object

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpresponse

I'm creating a custom module and I need to be able to read the html output that's written to the HttpResponse object. Can anyone provide direction on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Just for clarification, this is for a page in your application or for a page your are sending a request for in code using WebRequest/WebResponse

Comment: This is in an HttpModule. I need to analyze the HTML in the current response not get the response from a web page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you could intercept the data being written with a HttpResponse.Filter.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.filter.aspx

There is an example here:

http://aspnetresources.com/articles/HttpFilters

I have not tried it myself yet though.

Answer (score 2):

As André said, you may want to implement an HttpResponse filter. Alternatively to configuring the filter in the web.config file, you can also implement the following in the global.asax.cs file:

```
  protected void Application_BeginRequest() {
     Response.Filter = new PassThroughFilter(Response.Filter);
  }
```

The `PassThroughFilter` class derives from Stream and implements the abstract methods, then forwards them to the original filter.

For the full source code, see [my blog](http://manfredlange.blogspot.com/2010/07/using-http-response-filter-in-aspnet.html).